# Warning: No available formula with the name "mkcert"

Tags: macos, homebrew, mkcert

Im using a M1 mac and Im trying to install `mkcert` using `brew`,

The command that I use is:

```
brew install mkcert
```

This is the error that I get:

```
brew install mkcert                                                                            
fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision
Warning: No available formula with the name "mkcert".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I ended up doing is resolving this part:

> fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision

by following the most voted comment on this thread:
https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/1512
this is the solution the suggested:

```
rm -rf $(brew --repo homebrew/core)
brew tap homebrew/core
```